# Exclude jQuery From Specific Div Using CSS

Tags: javascript, css

The site uses this js which breaks the search-form input fields added within the site-branding div

```
/**
 * Remove all off-canvas states
 */
 function removeAllFocusStates() {
    'use strict';

    var siteBranding = document.getElementsByClassName('site-branding')[0];
    var getFocusedElements = siteBranding.querySelectorAll(':hover, :focus, :focus-within');
    var getFocusedClassElements = siteBranding.querySelectorAll('.is-focused');
    var i;
    var o;

    for (i = 0; i < getFocusedElements.length; i++) {
        getFocusedElements[i].blur();
    }

    for (o = 0; o < getFocusedClassElements.length; o++) {
        deleteClass(getFocusedClassElements[o], 'is-focused');
    }
}
```

Here's the HTML output for the site-branding container

```
<div class="site-branding">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://dev.local/">
        <label>
            <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
            <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
    </form>        
</div>
```

**Update** : Here's the **removeAllFocusStates()** function in use which needs modifying to exclude the **search-form**

```
  ...
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

      // Remove all focused menu states when clicking outside site branding
      if (event.target !== document.getElementsByClassName('site-branding')[0]) {
          removeAllFocusStates();
      } else {
          // nothing
      }

  }, false);
}
```

Users cannot enter text in the search input field because the js is modifying default input field.

Is there a way to use CSS to fix this so it doesn't apply to the search-form input field added within the site-branding div within the header?

Otherwise, is there a way to modify the js so it doesn't effect the search-form?

I did search the similar questions however couldn't find anything which applies specifically to this problem.

Comment: where did the `removeAllFocusStates ` call? After submit or initial?

Comment: Please see the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not calling `removeAllFocusStates()` when the user clicks the input.

So

```
if (event.target !== document.getElementsByClassName('site-branding')[0]) {
```

becomes something like

```
if ( (event.target !== document.getElementsByClassName('site-branding')[0]) && (event.target !== document.getElementsByClassName('search-field')[0]) ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS solution may not preferable in this case. It is because the problem is that `event.target` returns the clicked element (the input field) instead of the parent. So `event.target !== document.getElementsByClassName('site-branding')[0]` would not return true when you click on the input field inside `.site-branding`.

I suggest add the EventListener to `.site-branding` element, and watch if the clicked element has parent `.search-form`.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('site-branding')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  // Value of event.target would be the input field but not the parent.
  // So if you want to exclude element inside a specific parent,
  // try to select the target's parent.

  if (event.target.closest('.search-form') === null){ 
    removeAllFocusStates();
  } else {

  }
}, false);
```